# Developing NodeJS for Ubuntu Touch:

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, devices, nodejs

I'm new here and interested in developing apps for Ubuntu Touch. Already got the developer version running on a tablet model P3110.

What I'd like to know is if it's compatible with NodeJS or if it's possible to create apps using that technology given that I read it accepts Javascript.

Or is it better to use HTML5/QML? If so, why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### WebApps

As far as I know, HTML5 Web Applications which run on Ubuntu [Touch] are simply a Chromeless browser running your application "like" a native application in Ubuntu, with some [low-level API](http://developer.ubuntu.com/web/api/) to access a few features of Ubuntu (currently, only Desktop). So it doesn't matter what server-side language you use, Node.js or whatever.

### PhoneGap

We can't forget this one, ever. Phonegap supports Ubuntu, too. This initially means Ubuntu Desktop, but lemme quote this:

> Cross compiling applications for Ubuntu Touch on ARM is natively supported by the cordova-ubuntu platform support module, as of version 3.4 or superior.

So you can make Ubuntu applications which run on ARM-based CPUs, too.

[This is a list of APIs supported by PhoneGap](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/html5/current/)

### Native

Of course, native has always been the best choice, and probably will stay as the best for a while. If you want blazingly fast apps with access to every API, native is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

With QML applications there is a deep integration javascript ! And you can compile your application on Linux, Mac, windows, ubuntu touch, blackberry, android, ios, windows phone